# How to use master page of yii framework project in core php project?

Tags: javascript, php, yii, master-pages

I have two project one in yii framework and another is in core php project. I have managed every things like login and other part because both project have different database. But at last I am unable to provide the master page of yii framework project to the core php project.Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you have configure your vhost?

Comment: @ paistra I don't have vhost and don't have authentication for this too.

Comment: did you try htaccess rewrite roles ?

Comment: what did you want say by "dont have" you work on server or local ?

Comment: @Abudayah can you give idea on it to solve my problem

Comment: @paistra the final location is server.

Comment: so where are your probleme actually ?
you should configure your vhost in twice condition if you didn't it it's doesn't work ;)

Comment: @paistra the problem is that i am running two projects as on project both project are running smoothly but the condition is that old project  does not have master page so i want to use my yii project's master page on it.

Comment: So first configuret your vhost for this project :)

Comment: @paistra I know this will not provide solution for me so please refer the way solvig by coding in yii framework or core php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have any idea to implement directly but the simple but not so good idea is that you can put the header and footer on old project as in your new project with same design and same link.

Comment: I think this is a better idea. Thank you Kartoos.

Answer (score 0):

i wonder if it is possible?? I think Yii has its own process to render view... It may be possible if you could write a function to process your view like in Yii.

Comment: The process of writing the function is impossible because the old application is very vast so i am looking for the altenative